# D3.JS change text in axis ticks to custom strings

Tags: d3.js, text

I want to select each text element in each g.tick and change the text to be "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015" instead of 0, 4, 8, 12 respectively

[image: view in the web inspector]

I've tried first to grab all of these text elements as an array, but this was not working: var arrOfText = d3.selectAll("g.yaxis g.tick text")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into d3's [`axis.tickFormat([format])`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) function - it lets you specify how you want your data formatted.

Here's a simple example you can edit to fit your use case.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21])
    .tickFormat(function(d, i){ return "Num = " + d; });
```