# How to create a bar chart with custom string labels with d3 in angular?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, d3.js

I am using d3 in angular to create a bar chart of feelings from very bad (1) to very good (5) with the feelings as labels on the yAxis. I am running into an error: `Argument of type '(d: any, i: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`. I've been able to use "any" to get around similar type errors, but it isn't working in this part: `.tickFormat(function(d:any,i:any): any { return tickLabels[i] }) ;`

```
interface Datum {
    created_at: string,
    decription: string,
    feeling: string,
    feeling_attachments: any,
    feeling_in_number: number,
    id: number,
    tag_user_ids: string,
    tags: any,
    visibility: string
}

buildChart2(feels: Array<Datum>){
    var feelsData = feels.reverse()
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var ticks = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    var tickLabels = ['','very bad','bad','neutral','good','very good']

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickValues(ticks)
    .tickFormat(function(d:any,i:any): any { return tickLabels[i] }) ;

    var chart = d3.select(".feelsChart")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  y.domain([0, d3.max(feelsData, function(d: any): any { return d.feeling_in_number; })]);

  var barWidth = width / feelsData.length;

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(feelsData)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + i * barWidth + ",0)"; });

  bar.append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.feeling_in_number); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.feeling_in_number); })
  .attr("width", barWidth - 1);

  bar.append("text")
  .attr("x", barWidth / 2)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.feeling_in_number) + 3; })
  .attr("dy", ".75em");
  // .text(function(d) { return d.feeling_in_number; });

  chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");

    chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
}
```

I've been trying to work off Mike Bostock's [Let's Make A Bar Chart](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/) tutorial and a few other stack overflow questions about d3 in angular.

[D3.JS change text in axis ticks to custom strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018245/d3-js-change-text-in-axis-ticks-to-custom-strings)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue using the code in the question but I get the error "TS1005: '=>' expected" instead of the one you mention. Do you get the same error or does your code differ from what is in the question?

Comment: @hagner i havent gotten that error, but the code posted is exactly what im using

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to follow some guides that uses javascript with the older style of declaring functions. Typescript uses the newer ES6 syntax with arrow functions. So the function should be written like this in typescript:

```
.tickFormat((d:any, i:any): any => return tickLabels[i]);
```

You can read more about functions in typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html)